# Spring integration with Citrus: no output-channel or replyChannel header available

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, citrus-framework

Ive configured a test where I first send "Req" from a server to my application, and then respond to the server with "Rsp". I receive the request message successfully but then get the following error when trying to respond:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.wrapExceptionIfNecessary(AbstractDispatcher.java:133)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at com.consol.citrus.channel.ChannelProducer.send(ChannelProducer.java:66)
at com.consol.citrus.actions.SendMessageAction.doExecute(SendMessageAction.java:103)
at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.executeAction(TestCase.java:211)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:226)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
... 57 more
```

Please see my bean config below:
**citrus-config.xml**

```
<citrus:channel-endpoint id="citrusServiceReqEndpoint"
                         channel-name="req_transformed" />

<citrus:channel-endpoint id="citrusServiceRspEndpoint"
                         channel-name="rsp" />


<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
                               type="client" host="localhost" port="12345" single-use="false"
                               so-timeout="10000" using-nio="true" deserializer="javaSerializer"
                               serializer="javaSerializer" />

<bean id="javaSerializer"
      class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLfSerializer" />

<int:channel id="req" />

<int:channel id="req_transformed">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="rsp">
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="rsp_transformed">
</int:channel>

<int:object-to-string-transformer id="incomingTransformer" input-channel="req" output-channel="req_transformed" />

<int:object-to-string-transformer id="outgoingTransformer" input-channel="rsp" output-channel="rsp_transformed" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gateway"
                            connection-factory="client"
                            request-channel="req"
                            reply-channel="rsp_transformed"
                            client-mode="true" />
```

**Test case:**

```
receive("citrusServiceReqEndpoint").messageType(MessageType.PLAINTEXT).payload("Req");
        send("citrusServiceRspEndpoint").payload("Rsp");
        receive("citrusServiceReqEndpoint").messageType(MessageType.PLAINTEXT).payload("Req2");
        send("citrusServiceRspEndpoint").payload("Rsp2");
```

Basically, my intentions are to receive data on the "req" channel, then transform the bytes to a String onto the req_transformed channel and then validate that the String is equal to "Req". Then, I want to send a "Rsp" string back which is transformed into bytes and then put onto the rsp_transformed channel as the reply.

Please help me understand where the problem lies. Note that when I replace the tcp-inbound-gateway with two channel adapters:

```
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
            id="outboundClient" channel="rsp" connection-factory="client" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
            id="inboundClient" channel="req" connection-factory="client" client-mode="true" />
```

the test case works 100%. Why then would it not work with a gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tcp-inbound-gateway operates with synchronous messaging. Therefore you need to use a synchronous channel endpoint in Citrus accordingly.

```
<citrus:channel-sync-endpoint id="citrusServiceSyncEndpoint"
                     channel-name="req_transformed"/>
```

The synchronous endpoint will take care on special headers that correlate req/resp channels with request/reply. So your test looks like this:

```
receive("citrusServiceSyncEndpoint")
    .messageType(MessageType.PLAINTEXT)
    .payload("Req");
send("citrusServiceSyncEndpoint")
    .messageType(MessageType.PLAINTEXT)
    .payload("Rsp");
```

Please notice that the same synchronous endpoint is used for both request and response.

Comment: Wow both authors of their respective frameworks reply to my question and help me to solve it! Thank you very much kind sirs :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with citrus but when using a gateway, the response must contain certain headers from the request - specifically the `replyChannel` header in this case - that's how the gateway knows which request the reply is for (there may be many concurrent requests through the gateway).

You can use a pair of [collaborating TCP inbound/outbound channel adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#_collaborating_outbound_and_inbound_channel_adapters) instead of an inbound gateway but then you still need to tell the outbound adapter which socket the reply is for, by propagating the `ip_connectionId` header from the request to the reply.

Comment: Ok thanks I think this will help me a bit. I will probably have to put some component  before Citrus in the pipeline that will store the received header, and then populate the response with this value once it is sent.